# How to exclude class name to phpmd, cleancode ruelset?

Tags: php, testing, phpmd

When I run phpmd I get this error (from cleancode ruleset):
Avoid using static access to class '\Namespace\Domain\Exception\UserExceptions'

I make a phpmd.xml with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset>
   <rule ref="rulesets/cleancode.xml">
       <properties>
           <property name="exceptions" value="'\Namespace\Domain\Exception\UserExceptions'"/>
       </properties>
   </rule>
</ruleset>
```

But this not working for me, Is my syntax wrong to specify the class name?
I also try with: 
 `value="\Namespace\Domain\Exception\UserExceptions"`
 `value="UserExceptions"`
 `value="'UserExceptions'"`

but none of the options works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution!

```
<rule ref="rulesets/cleancode.xml">
    <exclude name="StaticAccess"/>
</rule>

<rule ref="rulesets/cleancode.xml/StaticAccess">
    <properties>
        <property name="exceptions">
            <value>
                \Laminas\Stdlib\ArrayUtils,
                otherClass
            </value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</rule>
```